# Compiled with problems: × ERROR in ./src/App.jsx 6:0-50 Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@material/-ui/icons'

Tags: reactjs

I got this error, and I'm not quite sure what is the compatibility issue is,

Problem:

```
Compiled with problems:
×
ERROR in ./src/App.jsx 6:0-50
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@material/-ui/icons' in 'C:\Users\yasri\OneDrive\Desktop\STUDY PROJECT\reactproj\src'
```

package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "reactproj",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.14.18",
    "@mui/material": "^5.14.18",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^6.1.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.5.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^3.5.0"
  }
```

Comment: seems it is missing some dependencies, try running npm i again, and if not try adding the respective module from npm

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a typo in your import statement. Try these:

```
import SomeIcon from '@mui/icons-material/SomeIcon';
```

Where `SomeIcon` is the icon your trying to import.

You can see the exact import statement for each MUI icon [here](https://mui.com/material-ui/material-icons/)

Answer (score 0):

***Try performing the following operation***

```js
npm i @material-ui/icons
```

The link to the exact package : https://www.npmjs.com/package/@material-ui/icons

This is what is missing. So either try to check if you are importing the correct package, else the above package installation should help.

Answer (score 0):

The import statement you provided contains an extra '**/**' in the module name.

It should be '**@material-ui/icons**' instead of '**@material/-ui/icons**'.

Consider correcting the import statement.